# Routes ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация

Пытаюсь изменить вид ссылки. Передаю параметр `name` с помощью `@Html.ActionLink`. Ссылка имеет вид:

```
/Account/Profile?name=имя_аккаунта
```

А я пытаюсь сделать такой вид:

```
/Profile/имя_аккаунта
```

В **RouteConfig** прописал:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Profile",                                          
        "Profile/{name}",                                   
        new { controller = "Account", action = "Profile", name = UrlParameter.Optional }   
    );
}
```

Но внешний вид ссылки не меняется. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить его первым в списке

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать хелпер Html.RouteLink вместо Html.ActionLink.
Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Профиль", "Profile", new { name = "account_name" })
```

То есть, первый параметр этого хелпера - это текст гиперссылки, второй параметр - это название маршрута, указанное в RouteConfig. Ну, и третьим параметром передаёте анонимный объект, содержащий необходимый параметр для отправки на сервер.